# WCF Data services - service operations not returning related entiities

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, wcf-data-services

I am working with EF 4.3 code first and using WCF Data services (5.0 just released) to expose the data over HTTP
I find that if I call a service operation from a browser I am able to get related entities back, but when I consume the service operation in a client app I am not getting back the related entities.
I have been researching this isuse it seems the EF enables lazy loading whn using the virtual key word when referencing a an ICollection, this some how prevents WCF data services  from returing realted entities - is this true
If i browse locally and put a break point on my getUsersByName method I can see the related group entity but when it comes over the wire to a client app the gropup entity is missing.
Is there a configuration to enable this.

Thanks
eg

```
 public partial class Group
    {
        public Group()
        {
            this.Users = new HashSet<User>();           
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int GroupID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a group name")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The group name is too long")]
        public string GroupName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Admin { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    }
    public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            this.Groups = new HashSet<Group>();
        }


        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a username")]
        [StringLength(50,ErrorMessage="Username is too long")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter an email address")]
        [RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+",ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public Test()
            : base("name=TestEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Tell Code First to ignore PluralizingTableName convention
            // If you keep this convention then the generated tables will have pluralized names.
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        }

        public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    }

    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]
    [JSONPSupportBehavior]
    public class TestSVC : DataService<TestContext>
    {

        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.SetServiceActionAccessRule("*", ServiceActionRights.Invoke);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
        }        

        [WebGet]
        public User GetUserByName(string userName)
        {
            var user = (from u in this.CurrentDataSource.Users
                       where u.UserName == userName
                       select u).FirstOrDefault();

            return user;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually regardless of what you do on the server side with the entity WCF DS will not return expanded entities by default. It's a feature. The reason is size of the message on the wire.
The client can request this behavior though (and that should work without making any modifications to the EF entities on the server side).

Let's assume you have a service operation GetProducts. You can issue a query like ~/GetProducts?$expand=Category which will include the Category entities in the result.

You also noted that the client doesn't get to see these, but you do see them in the browser. So are you already using the $expand? If that's the case the problem is solely on the client. Make sure that you request the results using the $expand on the client as well (depends on what code you're using, there's an Expand method in the LINQ on the client for this). And then you can use Fiddler to see if the client actually gets the results back the way you want. If that's the case and you still don't get the results in your client code, it might be due to MergeOptions. Try setting DataServiceContext.MergeOption to OverwriteChanges and try again (but be sure that you're aware of what this setting does).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the initialization of the navigation properties in the constructor  because it will create problems  with the proxy objects.

It's almost impossible to use lazy loading with serialization because when the serializer access the navigation properties the related entities will be loaded. This will lead to load whole database. So you need to disable lazy loading and use `Include` to load whatever you want or you can use some DTO with lazy loading enabled .